# How to use a Value from Table A in TABLE B using foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, oracle-apex

I'm simply trying to understand this concept.

I have

```
TABLE A:   ID | NAME | NUMBER
```

and

```
TABLE B:   ID | A_ID (FK) | ENTERED_NUMBER
```

How do I put data in `NUMBER` in `TABLE A` into `ENTERED_NUMBER` in `TABLE B`? How would the SQL look like?

Also, How would it look if you were to type the same SQL in Oracle APEX given that

TABLE A is on Page 2 and TABLE B is on Page 3

So therefore, their fields/labels would be

TABLE A

```
 { p2_ID, p2_NAME, p2_NUMBER }
```

TABLE B

```
{ p3_ID, p3_A_ID, p3_ENTERED_NUMBER }
```

Comment: Have you read some SQL tutorials?  This is probably one of easiest thing you can do.

Comment: If you can't even do a simple join, I would suggest you don't touch the database.  I hope it's not a production db.

Comment: It probably makes sense to have a look at how this is done in the sample schema. In apex you can load a number of sample schemas (SQL Workshop > utilities > sample datasets). The best one to start is the emp/dept schema. A foreign key relationship is there for you to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t. You join the two tables on the FK -> PK and retrieve the data that way

Comment: Understood. I'm fairly new to sql queries. Can you assist with how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Hi - considering this is pretty fundamental to how relational databases, and therefore SQL, work you’d should probably take an introduction to SQL course. There are plenty of free ones online

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this is how master-detail relationship looks like.

> Note: I renamed your `number` column; you can't name it that way, it is reserved for datatype so I used the `c_` prefix. You *could* have that name, though, if you enclose it into double quotes, but I wouldn't recommend you (nor anyone else) to do it.

```
SQL> create table tablea
  2    (id       number constraint pk_a primary key,
  3     name     varchar2(20),
  4     c_number number
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> create table tableb
  2    (id       number constraint pk_b primary key,
  3     a_id     number constraint fk_ba references tablea (id),
  4     col      varchar2(2)
  5    );

Table created.
```

There's no use in having the same column in both tables (that's what `tablea.c_number` and `tableb.entered_number` would be); you'd violate *normalization* and produce a little maintenance nightmare as you'd have to worry about inserts (put the same value into `tableb`), updates (what will you do if you update `tablea`? Modify `tableb`, probably. But, what if you modify `tableb` first? Will you propagate it back to master table, `tablea`?). Shortly - don't do that.

Several sample rows:

```
SQL> insert into tablea (id, name, c_number) values (1, 'Little', 100);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tablea (id, name, c_number) values (2, 'Foot', 101);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tableb (id, a_id, col) values (123, 1, 'X');

1 row created.
```

Query which joins those tables:

```
SQL> select a.id a_id, a.name, a.c_number, b.col
  2  from tablea a join tableb b on a.id = b.a_id;

      A_ID NAME                   C_NUMBER CO
---------- -------------------- ---------- --
         1 Little                      100 X

SQL>
```

---

As of Apex:

- put `tablea` items onto page 2
- put `tableb` items onto page 3
- create **link** on page 2 that leads to another page in this application (i.e. page 3).
- in link properties, set `P3_A_ID` item value to `P2_ID`. Doing so, when you navigate from page 2 to page 3, Apex will pre-populate `P3_A_ID` item with `P2_ID` value